# UINavigationBar Fade Position Problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

So, here's an interesting little problem I've had to deal with.  I coded a navigationBar to be translucent and the view underneath to be fullScreen.  When I load the view, I can tap on a clear button in the view to "activate" an animation that fades in the bar and other ui elements.

[image]

When I rotate the device WITH THE UI ELEMENTS VISIBLE it works perfectly.

But if I tap again to "turn off" the elements with a fade out animation, then rotate, it pushes the naivgationbar up into the status bar.

[image]

I don't understand why this happens.  I don't want to turn off the statusBar, but if I have to, I will.  Can anyone help me with the bar's autorotation positioning?

EDIT SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, this code animates the 20 pixels needed to move the bar down.

```
- (void)showToolbar
{

    if (toolbar.hidden == YES)
    {
        [self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^(void)
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];             
             toolbar.hidden = NO;
             toolbar.alpha = 1.0f;
             self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0f;
             CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
             frame.origin.y = 20.0;
             self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
         }
                         completion:NULL
         ];
    }
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar isHidden]) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; 
    }
}
```